# git apply patch exclude 2 files

Tags: git, git-patch, git-apply

How do you git apply patch but exclude 2 files? For 1 file or file pattern you could do `--exclude` flag. But what if I have 2 different files `a.rb` and `b.rb` I need to exclude but I have `c.rb`, `d.rb`, `e.rb` also in the patch which needs to be applied.

Comment: You seemed to have pointed it out yourself. Why not use a file pattern with `--exclude`? Something like: `git apply patch --exclude=[cde]\.rb`.

Comment: @miqh My files are complex than that. It will be more like `xqwxwqxwq.rb`, `kiloili.rb`, `errere.rb`. I am not familiar with patterns.

Comment: Note you can specify `--exclude` multiple times to avoid having to come up with a pattern that covers all file paths you'd like to include. That is: `git apply patch --exclude=donotwantthisfile.rb --exclude=nordoiwantthisfile.rb`. Conversely, if you want to flip the problem around, you can also use `--include` multiple times.

Comment: Unless this has to be automated, I'd fire up a text editor over the patch and remove what I don't want.

Comment: @Kaz Ah, you mean editing the patch file, that is also a good option. Didnt realize patch file was just a text file.

Comment: @miqh, would you please add example, how to exclude whole dir or dirs? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This could help

```
git apply -v mypatch.patch --exclude={file1.txt, file2.json}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude several `<path>` patterns using several `--exclude` flags:

```bash
git apply 2024_update.patch --exclude=a.rb --exclude=b.rb
```

Notice that if you are using the `--directory` flag, you need to exclude the path rewrite destination file not the original file path, for example:

```bash
git apply 2024_update.patch --directory='package/'\
  --exclude=package/a.rb\
  --exclude=package/b.rb
```

If you need to exclude a whole subdirectory `dir/` you can use:

```bash
git apply 2024_update.patch --exclude="dir/*"
```

Similarly to files, you can exclude several directories and you should also use the destination path `package/dir/*` in this example.